# AS3: Best way to include non-specific functions in to class

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Say I have the following set up of classes...

> **Road** - extends MovieClip  
> **Car** - extends Road 
>   **Controller** - extends Car

And I want to incorporate some common Mathematical functions in them all to make them faster e.g.(replacing Math classes with some speedy bitwise versions).

What is the best way to incorporate these functions into all of them without writing the functions in the classes or extending from class of the functions. Is importing the class into each the fastest way or is their a better way?

Comment: I can see how a `ControllableCar` would extend a `Car` - but `Car` extends `Road`?  I hope this is just a messed up example, otherwise you should re-design your code instead of applying micro optimisations.

Comment: Road consists of the Obstacles the car can hit, what is wrong with this? Micro optimisations are important as this is for a mobile app.

Comment: If the road consists of obstacles, then the car and the controller consist of the obstacles too. But I guess a car *is* an obstacle? I don't know the implementation but just reading the names sounds like wrong inheritance. Maybe Road should be called Obstacle instead? Sure, it doesn't affect the code but I think good names are important to understand the code.

Comment: @kapep I see what you mean and in an ideal world I would have both obstacles and controller extending car but then both would create a new car instance when I want only one. This was the way to minimise code, road caches bitmapdata about the car and its surroundings and has collision functions to perform when it hits them. Controller is an obstacle the car can hit also.

Comment: I think this question shows simple a misunderstanding of inheritance and composition. I think want you want to do is make `Road`, `Car`, `Controller` inherit from `MovieClip`(or `Sprite`). Then you would want `Road` to hold a reference to a `Car` object (or objects, e.g `Vector.<Car>`) and then Controller a reference of the `Car` object it controls.

Comment: I'm thinking Road and Obstacle extend MovieClip and Car, animals, debris, people can extend Obstacle, All obstacle types get added to road as children.

Comment: @Taurayi What do you mean by reference (am very new to OOP and just learning as I go a long plus this is my first package, I probably have done a lot of things wrong), I am just struggling to call functions of things and found inheritance a simple way to share these functions (although as I realise now this is a bad thing to do) so how would I reference and call upon a referenced classes functions (could solve a lot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a public function that you can import into any class. Some examples in the base language are navigateToURL() and getTimer(). These are just public functions in a package, not classes.
So create a public function like so

```
package nameOfYourPackage{

  public function doSomething(a:arguments):returnType
  {
    // Stuf the function does goes here;
  }
}
```

then you can import it into any class like so:

```
import nameOfYourPackage.doSomething;
```

and then youc an call it anywhere in a class that imports it as:

```
doSomething(args);
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments that your design may needs some work.  You can't use a Class in another Class without an import statement that refers to it in some way--even if you're just importing an Interface that the Class implements.

The most flexible way to handle this is to have the functional object be passed in to the object that needs it, rather than having that object create the instance itself.  This will allow you to swap out a different implementation when you need to (for instance, you might want to use a mock instance for unit testing, or you might need slightly different functionality optimized for a mobile device).

You can pass in the instance either in the Constructor or use a property (which would allow you the freedom to change out the implementation at runtime).